# Databricks spark snowflake dataframe.toPandas() taking more space and time

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 exactly same table(rows and schema). One table recides in AZSQL server data base and other one is in snowflake database. Now we have some existing code which we want to migrate from azsql to snowflake but when we are trying to create a pandas dataframe from the snowflake its takes 20 to 30 mins to do it(3.8 millon records) and in AZSQL same task, we are able to do it in 5 mins. Also to perfome toPandas for AZSQL we were using really small single node cluster and for snowflake we have to use a cluster with 56 gb of memory(otherwise we get OOM error).

I have asked same question to databricks community
https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D53f00001LKMhHCAX

Comment: Some information about what you are doing would probably be helpful: table structures, data volumes, the  code you are running, etc

Comment: how long does it take for Snowflake to run your original query? And how long does AZSQL take? You can test by using Snowflake/AZSQL to run the query directly without Databricks

Comment: There is not much of a difference while running the query on the databases, @pltc

Comment: @nickW I will provide shortly

Comment: I'm guessing your Databricks is Azure based, while Snowflake is AWS based? I'm also guessing Snowflake query might take some time to spin up the cluster before running the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please find my answer and code here
https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D53f00001LKMhHCAX

the summary:
python doesn't understand decimal data type so spark treats it as object type.